# Cargar archivos a través de Javascript Base64

Tags: javascript, servlets, base64

Estimados ojalá puedan ayudarme

Tengo un pequeño problema, estoy intentando generar un modal que me permita subir un archivo (pdf) en base64 por Java...
El inconveniente surge al momento de capturar (Description y el Archivo) el tipo de archivo sí lo obtiene

El dato  HTML esta a través de un formulario con metodo form y al momento de capturar se me ha complicado ya que intento imprimir por consola y solo muestra la linea html incluso intentado solicitar un .value

```js
var fileg = [];

function cargarArchivoPDF(elemento) {
  var file = elemento.files[0];

  var tipo = file.name.substr(-4, 4);

  if (tipo == ".pdf") {
    $("#tipoA").val("pdf");
    swal({
      title: clearStringJS("La operaci\u00f3n tuvo \u00e9xito"),
      text: clearStringJS("Archivo Compatible"),
      closeOnConfirm: true
    });
    $("#cargarPDF").attr("disabled", false);
    tipo = "";
  } else if (tipo == ".jpg") {
    $("#tipoA").val("jpg");
    swal({
      title: clearStringJS("La operaci\u00f3n tuvo \u00e9xito"),
      text: clearStringJS("Archivo Compatible"),
      closeOnConfirm: true
    });
    $("#cargarPDF").attr("disabled", false);
    tipo = "";
  } else {
    swal({
      title: clearStringJS("Ha ocurrido un problema"),
      text: clearStringJS("Archivo Incompatible"),
      closeOnConfirm: true
    });
    $("#cargarPDF").attr("disabled", true);
    tipo = "";
  }

  fileg = file;

  document.formaulario.target = "null";
  // document.formaulario.action = "Ingresar_Archivo_Adjunto";
  // document.formaulario.submit();

}

function subirArchivo(fileg) {

  var validacionDatos = validarIngresoDocumento();
  if (validacionDatos === 1) {

    var Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona = document.formaulario.Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona;
    var description = document.formaulario.description.value;
    console.log("description1 ");
    console.log(description);
    fileg;
    console.log("fileg ");
    console.log(fileg);
    var tipoA = document.formaulario.tipoA;
    document.formaulario.action = "Ingresar_Archivo_Adjunto";
    swal("Archivo Cargado Correctamente");
    limpiarModal();
    console.log("Archivo NUEO");

  } else {
    msjeRechazado("Faltan datos por ingresar. Revise la informaci\u00f3n antes de realizar la asignaci\u00f3n.");
    console.log("no hay Archivo NUEO");
  }
}

function validarIngresoDocumento() {
  var description = $("#description").val();
  console.log("description " + description);
  if (description.length <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;

}

function onkeyTextOnly(id) {
  var texto = $("#" + id).val();
  texto = texto.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""); // solo deja pasar letras, tildes y dieresis
  texto = $("#" + id).val(texto);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal inmodal" id="modal_agregar_PDF_postulantes" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close btnModalGFijosCerrar" onclick="cerrarAgregarPDF();" data-dismiss="modal">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Agregar&nbsp;Documentos</h4>
        <small class="font-bold">Cargar los Documentos.</small>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
              <div class="ibox-content">
                <form name="formaulario" id="formaulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <input type="hidden" name="Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona" id="Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="tipoA" id="tipoA">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" name="description" id="description" onblur="onkeyTextOnly('description');" onkeyup="onkeyTextOnly('description');" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <label class="control-label"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="control-label">Archivo</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="file" name="file" onchange="cargarArchivoPDF(this)" accept=".pdf,.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <label class="control-label"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <input type="submit" id="cargarPDF" onclick="subirArchivo()" class="col-sm-12 btn btn-primary" class="form-control" value="Enviar" />

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <iframe name="null" style="display:none;"></iframe>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="btnCerrarModalAgregarPDF" type="button" class="btn btn-white" onclick="cerrarAgregarPDF();" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAva

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

//      ArrayList<Respuesta> RespuestaList  = new ArrayList<Respuesta>();

        String RespuestaList ="";




        /****************** datos servicio **********************/

        String  url_ws          =   Propiedades.url_ws,
                servicio        =   Propiedades.servicio_Archivo_Adjunto,
                metodo_ws       =   "Insertar_Archivo_Adjunto";

        /******************** datos pos consola **********************/

        String description = request.getParameter("description"); // Retrieves <input type="text" name="description">
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
        String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.
        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
        byte[] arr = readFully(fileContent); // convierte el inputStream en un Array de bytes.          
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arr);//Archivo en base64  

        String  tipoA           =   request.getParameter("tipoA");
        int Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona"));


        System.out.println("description " +description);
        System.out.println("encoded "+encoded);
        System.out.println("Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona "+Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona);
        System.out.println("tipoA "+tipoA);

        try {
//          Subir_ArchivosData sad = new Subir_ArchivosData();
            RespuestaList   =   new Subir_ArchivosData().subirDocumentacionPostulante(url_ws+servicio, metodo_ws,encoded, Id_Detalle_Ficha_Persona, description,tipoA);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(RespuestaList);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
        System.out.println(RespuestaList);

    }

    public static byte[] readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return output.toByteArray();
    }
```

Si necesitan otro dato favor, lo edito...

*Error de consola*

description1

```
<input id="description" class="form-control" type="text" name="description" onblur="onkeyTextOnly('description');" onkeyup="onkeyTextOnly('description');">
```

fileg 
undefined

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor pon un ejemplo de tu saldia de consola, seguro eso ayudará a más de uno.

Comment: description1 
<input id="description" class="form-control" type="text" name="description" onblur="onkeyTextOnly('description');" onkeyup="onkeyTextOnly('description');">

fileg 
undefined

Comment: Hola, puedes usar el botón [edit] para agregar los datos que hagan falta a la pregunta. Se pierde el sentido agregando datos en los comentarios. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Listo

Comment: `subirArchivo()` recibe un parametro

Comment: @JackNavaRow no deberia, ya que los trae por documento, pero le puse el fileg para ver si pasaba algo... xD